# html or js - to create large amount of similar html tags in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am working on a page where I need to have some similar trees (kind of) and leaves on them and have lots of them, as in like spanning across page width at page bottom. I was thinking of doing it 2 ways, one could be to just create one set first (tree and leave) and then clone it using jquery OR the other could be to basically write html tags for ALL of them in the page itself. Obviously that would mean having lots of html tags.

HTML for a tree group:

```
    <div class="tree-group-avg">
            <div class="small-tree">
                <span class="left-leaf"></span>
                <span class="right-leaf"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="avg-tree">
                <span class="left-leaf"></span>
                <span class="right-leaf"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="large-tree">
                <span class="left-leaf"></span>
                <span class="right-leaf"></span>
            </div>            
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.tree-group-avg {margin:0 15px;display:inline-block; }
.tree-group-avg div {position:relative;}
.tree-group-avg .large-tree {background:#83919F; width:2px; height:70px; display:inline-block; margin:0 5px -5px 0}
.tree-group-avg .avg-tree {background:#83919F; width:2px; height:50px; display:inline-block; margin:0 5px -5px 0}
.tree-group-avg .small-tree {background:#83919F; width:2px; height:30px; display:inline-block; margin:0 5px -5px 0} 
.left-leaf {width:10px; height:10px; border-radius:0 10px 0 10px; display:inline-block; background:#ACCF37; position:absolute; left:-10px;}
.right-leaf {width:10px; height:10px; border-radius:10px 0 10px 0; display:inline-block; background:#ACCF37; position:absolute; top:15px;}
```

The thing I have to take care is that height of tree is different, so it would be possible that I need 3 leaves on bigger trees than smaller one's. For that I thought of two ways, either directly use different leaves in html with different css "top" property value OR get this entire thing done through js or jquery, where in it calculate height of tree and modified "top" value of each leaf.

jsfiddle for a set : http://jsfiddle.net/npT47/

Exact image for what is to be acheived: [image]

Comment: You should use `for` loop of JS to loop the leaves on the tree!

Answer (score 2):

HTML and JS are both different, you cannot create pages by just writing snippets of JS, and you cannot create `Dynamic` web pages just by using HTML.

You need to meld both.

I have seen your fiddle, great work upto now. But what I found in common was that you are creating a lead after a common interval, lets say `10px` each. After 10 px you are creating a new leaf. And height is also common, for each tree the height increases almost `5px`. You can use such other features of them in JS, and create the tree!

You can use a `for` loop of JS and create the tree but just increase the size of the tree after each loop, `loop` will take care of that for you. You just need to be sure of what you're writing would create a tree. And note that trees that would grow will be of a common size increase and leaves would increase at a common number `int`.

Comment: Well, the positioning of the leaves was just approximate in the code. This will need changing and it all depends on how long the tree is and then accordingly leaves can be attached. I can surely use js loop for creating the complete structure. BTW, I just added an image in original post of what it looks like. What I was most interested in knowing is that should I do this by only writing html (will have lots of div and span) OR use JS and loop through building trees and then loop through attaching leaves.

Comment: What I would recommend would be of course JS, because with JS you will have to write only a few lines and JS would loop it under certain conditions. HTML can't do that!

Comment: Your image has 6 tree in a row! Then the image repeats again! This way, create a loop :)

Comment: Well, sounds easy with js, I would completely agree as far the image and looping goes. But dont you think writing HTML for this would save bandwidth, as that would be less amount of data sent to server, as compared to js one. Just curious.

Comment: Nah, HTML would cause bandwidth! Suppose a simple HTML markup would catch upto 5KB, JS? its just a jQuery plugin. And you're also not sending anything to server, once the request has been captured! Nothing is sent to server or recieved from server by JS untill you use Ajax!

Comment: And also note that using HTML would use more like next to 500 lines, but JS would use just 50 lines! Bandwidth friendly :)

Answer (score 2):

I have edited your fiddle. I have added divs dynamically in your html as I understood using jquery. Just look at this fiddle.  [jsfiddle.net/npT47/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/npT47/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tree="";
    var treeClass=["small-tree","avg-tree","large-tree"];
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
        tree+='<div class="'+treeClass[i]+'">'+
            '<span class="left-leaf"></span>'+
                '<span class="right-leaf"></span></div>';

    }    
    $("#treeDiv").html(tree);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I just added an image in original post. What I was most interested in knowing is that should I do this by only writing html (will have lots of div and span) OR use JS and loop through building trees and then loop through attaching leaves?

Comment: I think using java script for looping will be best option for you rather then adding static html in your page. You can also take random index using random() of javascript for generating different size of trees.

Comment: random()...hmm..sounds interesting..I will try this along. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve the exact same as the image you uploaded i would say HTML. The loop that you have to create will need a base HTML for the loop (which can be cloned) that is as wide as half your image (31 trees (because the pattern ends there). So you would end up writing lots of HTML either way.

The only way JS can be better is if you need full width coverage (viewport) and thus need to calculate the amount of repetitions needed.

Comment: well, this image will span across entire width of browser and I am developing for a fixed resolution. And I have a little flexibility to change the pattern, as and when required. So, would HTML be still the best option. I just want to weigh which option would be more effective/is as per best practice/doesn't eat performance  1) with writing lots of HTML for this OR 2) use JS for looping and do this.

Comment: When writing for a fixed resolution i would still go for the HTML solution. Why bother the client with generating HTML when sending it only takes up to a few KB.

Comment: Hmm.. I also thought so. HTMl would make sense here.. Thanks for that.